# $virtualFields and $belongsto collide, solution?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I am still using cake 2.5.3, but I couldnt find anything related in the updates. My problem is, the belongsto collides with the vitualfields in another Model.

First I made a Model for Projects:

```
class Project extends AppModel {
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Responsibleperson' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'responsibleperson_id'
    ),
    'Creator' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'creator_id'
    ),
);
}
```

The Person responsible and the person qho created the project may be different, but they are both users.

This works fine. Really.

Lateron I added in the User Model following:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'fullname' => 'CONCAT(User.prename, " ", User.name)'
);
```

Now nearly any $this->Project->find() call in the controller fails with

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.vorname' in 'field list'
```

When you look at the mysql-query, you see that the Query did not take over the changed Model name and it is still serarching for a User...

```
SELECT 
`Project`.`id`, 
`Project`.`projectname`, 
`Project`.`responsibleperson_id`, 
`Project`.`creator_id`, 
`Responsibleperson`.`id`, 
`Responsibleperson`.`username`, 
`Responsibleperson`.`prename`, 
`Responsibleperson`.`name`, 
(CONCAT(`User`.`prename`, " ", `User`.`name`)) AS `Responsibleperson__fullname`, 
`Creator`.`id`, 
`Creator`.`username`,  
`Creator`.`prename`, 
`Creator`.`name`, 
(CONCAT(`User`.`prename`, " ", `User`.`name`)) AS `Creator__fullname` 
FROM 
`database`.`projects` AS `Project` 
LEFT JOIN 
`database`.`users` AS `Responsibleperson` 
ON 
(`Project`.`responsibleperson_id` = `Responsibleperson`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN 
`swdevel`.`plantbook_users` AS `Creator` 
ON 
(`Project`.`creator_id` = `Creator`.`id`) 
WHERE 
(`Project`.`projektname` LIKE '%Searchsometing%')
```

Leaving the "User" in the virtual field away and just writing CONCAT(prename, " ", name), would make it abigous. How do I teach cake to change the Model name for the virtual fields?

Is there any solution except making a view in the database to have a "second" Model?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `virtualFields` in the `User` constructor to deal with model alias:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
        $this->virtualFields['fullname'] = sprintf(
            'CONCAT(%s.prename, " ", %s.name)', $this->alias, $this->alias
        );
    }

}
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases